# How can I resolve my null error coming to @role.Name below?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
@foreach (var a in Model.USERS.OrderBy(p => p.NAMESURNAME))
{
    var role = Model.ROLLER.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == a.ROLID);
    <tr id="tr@(a.ID)">
        <td>@a.NAMESURNAME</td>
        <td>@a.USERNAME</td>
        <td style="width:120px">@a.GOREV</td>
        <td>@a.EMAIL</td>
        <td>@a.PHONENUMBER</td>
        <td>@role.NAME</td>
        <td>@a.VERSİON</td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="AddUser" asp-route-userId="@a.ID" data-container="body" data-toggle="m-popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Edit"><i class="flaticon-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="delete" data-id="@a.ID" data-id2="@a.NAMESURNAME" data-container="body" data-toggle="m-popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Delete"><i class="flaticon-delete"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

role was null.

Comment: `var role = Model.ROLLER.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == a.ROLID);` => if there is no matching Id parameters, rol object set as null. When you try to reach null object property, you see NullReferenceException. Can you try `@role?.Name ?? string.Empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) method returns the first element of a
> sequence, or a default value if no element is found. The default value for reference and nullable types is `null`.

Therefore, it is necessary to use [Null-conditional operators `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to prevent the `System.NullReferenceException` exception:

```
<td>@role?.NAME</td>
```